# 500 internal server error ajax datatables codeigniter (database query)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, datatables

i've tried some answer from another question, but i really didnt know how to fix my code....please help how to fix this.

i want to display data from mysql database to datatables, its work really well when i display all of data, but when i used where clause it's show 500 internal server error.

this is my view

```
                   <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="table-responsive">                       
                      <table id="orgAkt_data" class="table table-striped table-hover">
                        <thead>
                          <tr>
                            <th>#</th>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Place</th>
                            <th>Category</th>
                          </tr>
                        </thead>        
                      </table>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <script>
                    $(document).ready(function(){  
                      var dataTable = $('#okas_data').DataTable({  
                         "processing":true,  
                         "serverSide":true,  
                         "order":[],  
                         "ajax":{  
                              url:"<?php echo base_url() . 'PruCtrl/fetch_okastable'; ?>",  
                              type:"POST"  
                         },  
                         "columnDefs":[{    
                            "orderable":false,  
                          },  
                        ],  
                      });
                    </script>
```

here's my controller

```
 function fetch_okastable(){  
$id_p = $this->session->userdata("id_p"); 
$load_data = $this->Pru_model->make_okas_tables($id_p);  
$data = array();  
$no = 1;
foreach($load_data as $row){  

  $sub_array[] = $no++;  
  $sub_array[] = $row->name;
  $sub_array[] = $row->place;
  $sub_array[] = $row->category;
  $sub_array[] = '<button type="button" name="update" id="'.$row->id.'" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs">Update</button>';
  $sub_array[] = '<button type="button" name="delete" id="'.$row->id.'" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs delete"> <i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>'; 
  $data[] = $sub_array;  
}  
$output = array(  
  "draw"                    =>     intval($_POST["draw"]),  
  "recordsTotal"            =>      $this->Pru_model->get_all_data(),  
  "recordsFiltered"         =>     $this->Pru_model->get_filtered_org(),  
  "data"                    =>     $data  
);  
echo json_encode($output);
```

}

and here's my ci model

```
 var $okas_table = "okas_table";
var $select_column = array("id","id_p","name","place","category","img");
var $order_column =  array(null,"id_p","name","place","category",null); 
function make_query_okas($id_p){  
       $this->db->select($this->select_column);  
       $this->db->from($this->org_akt_table); 
       $this->db->where("id_p",$id_p); 
       if(isset($_POST["search"]["value"]))  
       {  
            $this->db->like("id",$_POST["search"]["value"]);
            $this->db->or_like("name", $_POST["search"]["value"]);  
            $this->db->or_like("place", $_POST["search"]["value"]);
            $this->db->or_like("category", $_POST["search"]["value"]);  
       }  
       if(isset($_POST["order"]))  
       {  
            $this->db->order_by($this->order_column[$_POST['order']['0']['column']], $_POST['order']['0']['dir']);  
       }  
       else  
       {  
            $this->db->order_by('id', 'DESC');  
       }
}
function make_okas_tables($nim){  
  $this->make_query_okas($nim);  
  if($_POST["length"] != -1)  
       {  
            $this->db->limit($_POST['length'], $_POST['start']);  
       }  
       $query = $this->db->get();  
       return $query->result();  
} 
function get_filtered_okas(){  
       $this->make_query_okas();  
       $query = $this->db->get();  
       return $query->num_rows();  
}
function get_all_data(){  
       $this->db->select("*");  
       $this->db->from($this->okas_table);  
       return $this->db->count_all_results();  
}
```

Comment: Can you check error log? there would be some more information like due to which line of php code this 500 error is coming up.

Comment: is category char or int,

Comment: if its a db error, you should be able to see in network tab

Comment: Too few arguments to function Profil_model::make_query_okas(), 0 passed in "show this message in network"

Comment: the category is varchar